# How to add an orderby to a typo3 flow queryBuilder query?

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder, typo3-flow

This is my code, all I did to the exeisting working code is add the orderby:

```
$queryBuilder->select('pa1')
            ->from('\SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\ProductArticle', 'pa1')
            ->join('pa1.productPrices', 'pp1')
            ->join('pa1.product', 'p')
            ->where('pp1.salePrice IN (' . $subQueryBuilder . ') AND pa1.status = ' . \SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\ProductArticle::STATUS_ACTIVE . ' AND (pa1.stock > 0 OR pa1.displayOutOfStock = 1) AND p.status = ' . \SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\Product::STATUS_ACTIVE . ' AND p.isFeatured = 1 AND p.deleted = 0')
            ->groupBy('p')
            ->orderBy('p.isgiftcard', 'ASC');
    $result = $query->execute();
```

doesn't seem to work, it gives me the  exception:

```
MetaDataController.php line 176
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: generally you should only select and order by fields in your group by

Comment: Try outputing the DQL and SQL generated by the query builder, perhaps it will give you some clues.
$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL();
$queryBuilder->getDLQ();

Comment: fkuppper - I get an exception when I hit the select line so I cannot even get to the run that command.  I got around this problem by runnning two select statements - one for selecting non-gift-card items then later to select just giftcards then I can just append the gift cards to the first array.  Ugly solution but good enough for now.